How to style text with image, stroke and shadow simultaneously
I wan't to style my text with a background image, a text-stroke and also a text-shadow.
My problem is that the text-shadow comes on top of the background image. Does anybody know how I can put the shadow behind the image?
If you run the snippet. You will see that my text-shadow is on top of the image. Try to remove the text-shadow prompt and see the difference.
Thank you for your time.


.letsgo {
  font-family: Catamaran, sans-serif;
  font-size: 10em;
  background-image: url(https://files.cargocollective.com/c2106023/Unavngivet.png);
  background-size: contain;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -moz-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 1px #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 6px #CE5937, 8px 10px 6px #3D79CE, 8px 3px 2px #D782A5;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<a class="letsgo">here is my text</a>

</html>




I'm unclear exactly what you want the result to look like. Is it that all the red bit of the text should be 'see thro' i.e. we see the background through the character but the yellow outline stroke and the blueish behind shadow should remain, or is there some other effect you are after?

Try using CSS pseudo-elements like ::before and ::after and adding the text image to the original text, while applying the shadow through ::after
See this example:


.letsgo {
  font-family: Catamaran, sans-serif;
  font-size: 10em;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-image: url(https://files.cargocollective.com/c2106023/Unavngivet.png);
  background-clip: text;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  color: transparent;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

.letsgo::after {
  content: attr(data-text);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  color: transparent;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -moz-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 1px #fff;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 6px #CE5937, 8px 10px 6px #3D79CE, 8px 3px 2px #D782A5;
}
<a class="letsgo" data-text="here is my text">here is my text</a>




Thanks for your suggestion.
I can't make the ::after pseudo element work. I even tried with your specific code, but no luck. I don't know where to go from there.

can you elaborate what output you are getting on using ::after and your code using it

I don't get anything. It doesn't add any of the style from the ::after prompt

What's your code? could you create a jsfiddle or something similar

@NoCSStoday when I run the snippet (Edge/Windows10) I see the background image thro' the characters and they are each  in yellow and with a fuzzy blueish shadow. What browser and OS are you using?

Hi, I'm using chrome and windows 10.

@tanishq thanks for your help. I'm not experienced using Jfiddle. I think I've given up for now. Thanks for your suggestions.
